# Why would Cheerio work on a local development machine in a webapp, but not when the webapp is deployed on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cheerio

I have a web app that utilizes Cheerio to do some scraping for data. I use it to **scrape** multiple pages from different servers successfully.

All of those pages work on my local Visual Studio Code, NodeJS workstation running the webapp. One of the websites that I scrape for data does not work when webapp running on Heroku. It used to work just fine.

Any help appreciated.

This is the code that makes the call.

var options = {

```
  url: apcURL,

  headers: {

    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16'
  }
}

request(options, function (error, response, html) {
  let localHTML = html;
  // Define our data template
  var data = [];
  // Make request for Alabama Power Company site, returns html
  //request(apcURL, function (error, response, html) {

  // Load the HTML into cheerio and save it to a variable
  // '$' becomes a shorthand for cheerio's selector commands, much like jQuery's '$'

  if (error) {
    callback(error);
  } else {
    let dataErrorTrue = false;
    try {
      var $ = cheerio.load(localHTML);
```

localHTML is returned with "error code: 1020"

I don't understand why it works on my development machine, but not deployed.

Comment: That's a cloudflare error. They're blocking you.

Comment: Simply by domain?

Comment: It's because they can tell the traffic is coming from a datacenter.